# why show me the last object i put in txt

Tags: java

I have a big problem , I write in a txt file same objects Accounts when i click to see all objects i have write in txt is show me the last one only and how i show up the account in JOptionPane , the second is how i can make the account to take nuber one ,two , three...... every account i write to take a number plus one from the precedent account .
I believ to explain apparent

```
 if( str.equals("Receipt") )
 {
      ObjectInputStream in = null;
      Account acc = null;
      try
      {
           in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Accounts.txt"));
           while( (acc = (Account) in.readObject()) !=null)
           {
                if (acc instanceof Account)
                     ((Account)acc).print();
                //acc.print();
           }
      }
      catch(EOFException ex)
      {
           System.out.println("End of file reached.");
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
      {
           System.out.println("Error casting");
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
      {
           System.out.println("Error specified file does not exist");
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(IOException ex)
      {
           System.out.println("Error with I/O processes");
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
           try
           {
                in.close();
           }
           catch(IOException ex)
           {
                System.out.println("Another IOException during the closing");
                ex.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
 }
```

code to write object in file

```
Account ac=new Account(posoOfil,poso,ariLoga,aitiol,diafor); 
      ac.print();

      try{

      OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("Accounts.txt");
      OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream( file );
      ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream( buffer );
      try{
        output.writeObject(ac);
        output.flush();

System.out.println("Object written to file");
      }
      finally{
        output.close();
      }
    }
      catch
(FileNotFoundException ex) {System.out.println("Error with specified file") ;
ex.printStackTrace();}

    catch(IOException ex){
      System.out.println("Cannot perform output.");
    }

      }
```

And the class Account

```
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private int arithmKat;
 // private Date date ;
    private int posoOfil;
    private int posoKat;
    private String ariLoga ;
    private String aitiol;
    private boolean diafor=false;

    public Account(int posoOfil, int posoKat,String ariLoga,String aitiol,boolean diafor){
    arithmKat++;
    this.posoOfil=posoOfil;
    this.posoKat=posoKat;
    this.ariLoga=ariLoga;
    this.aitiol=aitiol;
    this.diafor=diafor;

    }
    void print(){
    System.out.println(arithmKat+"  "+posoOfil+"  "+posoKat+"  "+diafor);}

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format your code. It's unreadable at the moment.

Comment: Please reformat your code so that it can actually be read by a human.

Comment: That actually took a lot of effort. >.>

Comment: There was a random `catch` commented out

Comment: Show us how you write to the file. Also notes that an Account will always be an instance of Account, and that a file containing serialized accounts should not be named Accounts.txt, since it doesn't contain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only write **one** account to the file. There is no loop at all in the code writing the account. Code that would write several accounts would look like this:

```
private void writeAccounts(List<Account> accounts) throws IOException {
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("Accounts.txt");
    OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);

    try {
        for (Account account : accounts) {        
            output.writeObject(account);
        }
        output.close();
    }
    finally {
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: where i put the loop?
with for or while ?

Comment: If you have several accounts to write, you should open the output stream, loop though your accounts and write each of them, then close the output stream. Whether you use a while or a for is irrelevant. DO as you prefer.

Comment: i dont understound where i make the loop.

Comment: See my edit. Using loops is a really basic stuff you should master before thinking about doing IO.